# Почему не отображается картинка в браузере?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Доброго времени суток!

На локальном сайте был создан отдельный файл где все частности были заменены на вывод определённых переменных в php (статей из базы) с определёнными значениями id
 Можно было бы в базе делать отдельное поле и для картинок, но у меня сайт простой и получается каждая картинка имеет номер article_1.png (к примеру) и в full_arcticle тоже через подчёркивание .png" alt="" /> все статьи имеют формат phg. В intro_text (превью) - это работает все. В подробнее full_arcticle - нет (

В итоге -full-text статьи подгружается из базы данных нормально, но картинка нет. 
В браузере - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

GET mysite.local/www/images/article_.png 404 (Not Found)

[image: 1]

full_article.php

```html
<div class="article">
    <h1><?php echo $title;?></h1>

 <p class="article_img">
<img src="images/article_<?php echo $id;?>.png" alt="<?php echo $title;?>" />
 </p>
 <?php echo $full_text;?>
 
</div>
```

functions.php

```html
<?php

 $mysqli = false;
 function connectDB() {
  global $mysqli;
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "mysite-local");
  $mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8',");
 }

 function getAllArticles () {
  global $mysqli;
  connectDB();
  $result_set = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `articles`");
  closeDB();
  return resultSetToArray($result_set);
 }

 function getArticle($id) {
  global $mysqli;
  connectDB();
  $result_set = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `id`='$id'");
  closeDB();
  return $result_set->fetch_assoc();
 }
 
 function resultSetToArray($result_set) {
  $array = array();
  while (($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc()) !=false) 
  $array [] = $row;
  return $array;
  }

 function closeDB() {
  global $mysqli;
  $mysqli->close();
 }
?>
```

Comment: В $id ничего нет. Очевидно же.

Comment: извиняюсь за тупой вопрос- но как это изменить и где? я только начинаю изучать php

Comment: Где - в месте вызова full_article.php. Нужно передать параметр $id.

Comment: @ Эникейщик у меня в arcticle вначале  <?php
 require_once "start.php";
 $article = getArticle ($_GET["id"]);
 $title = $article["title"];
 $full_text = $article["full_text"];
?>   а в теле <?php
      require_once "blocks/full_article.php";
    ?>

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо добавить параметр id в article.php

```html
<?php
 require_once "start.php";
 $article = getArticle ($_GET["id"]);
 $id = $article["id"];
 $title = $article["title"];
 $full_text = $article["full_text"];
?>
```